# fixed timer and random direction

Tags: java, random, timer

Hello as a starting Java programmer I am busy creating a simple Pacman game in Java just to exercise and I have created a method for the ghost to move randomly horizontal of vertical but I have a few problems with it I don't know how to force it to go left-right or up-down (so not at the same time) my code for the ghost right now is as follows:

```
 public void moveUp() {

 }

 public void moveLeft() {

     if (g1x >= 500) { g1x = 500; g1r = false; }
     else if (g1x <= 0) { g1x = 0; g1r = true; }

 }

 public void moveRight() {

     if (g1x >= 500) { g1x = 500; g1r = false; }
     else if (g1x <= 0) { g1x = 0; g1r = true; }

 }

 public void moveDown() {

 }

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);
    // pacman movement
    diameter = 25;   
    pacman.drawPacMan(g, getHorPlaats(), getVerPlaats(), diameter, getView(), Color.yellow);

    // ghosts movement
    g1x += ghostSpeed * (Math.random() > 0.5? 1 : -1); // random direction

     Random randomGen = new Random();
     // generate a random number, between 0 - 3
     int randomize = randomGen.nextInt(4);

    switch(randomize) {
     case 0:
         moveUp();
         System.out.println("up");
         break;
     case 1:
         moveLeft();
         System.out.println("Left");
         break;
     case 2:
         moveRight();
         System.out.println("Right");
         break;
     case 3:
         moveDown();
         System.out.println("down");
         break;
    }

    ghost.drawGhost(g, randomize, 40, diameter, Color.red);

}
```

I have used the randomize variable for the direction as you can see and the horizontal position is hardcoded but the horizontal position is also stated by randomize but if I use it for both it makes some weird diagonal movements

the next problem is that i use a timer in my construction like this

```
    public PacMan() {

    // create timer and start timer
            javax.swing.Timer autoKlik = new javax.swing.Timer(WACHTTIJD, this);

            autoKlik.start();
}
```

so the random values for the directions is changing to fast ( 500ms ) but the speed also configures the gameplay speed so I think I made a logical mistake but Im not sure how to solve this.. do I have to seperate the actions maybe? or is there a easier way to achieve this please share your skills with me I am motivated to learn :) and if you might need more code I could post it here or give a link to my github account so you can check it out :)

Thanks in advance!

link to the full source: [pacman game source](https://github.com/reshadf/Java/tree/master/DeBasis/src/h04PacMan)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to separate the concerns:

- a set of classes to model the simulation contains only the entities and the logic
- a set of graphic classes which draw the pacman
- a controller to handle actions and delegate them to the model, fired by the swing classes

In paint() method, for performance reason, do only the painting, NEVER 'new' nor call complex methods. Paint are called very often by the framework.

Comment: I have seperated the drawing of pacman and the ghost already and also a few other stuff. but what do you mean with the first and the last one is what i'm trying to do now. for the new Random in paint() i did that so that the random value changes every time automatically how do you suggest this without putting it in the paint()? p.s. I have added the full source link for a better view of what I have at the moment.

Comment: Graphic operations should be automatic, without complex computation. Periodic moves should handled elsewhere, like user interactions. The model drives the drawing by building lists of fragment or moved entities which have to be painted. Model produces some forms and paint draws the forms.